# Form Stripe Credit Card not displaying on wordpress using Woocommerce Stripe

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

i found many errors when i click inspecter Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 499 () `https://q.stripe.com/...`

Comment: Can you provide more details about your integration? How are you including the Stripe form? Do you have screenshots of the problem? Is it accessible online for others to reproduce? You also may with to reach out to WooCommerce support for assistance with your integration using their plugin.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP74f.jpg

Comment: Can you share more details of your integration? How are you integrating Stripe? How is this error triggered?